DataTables FixedColumn is only fixed after page resize
I am implementing JQuery DataTables with the fixedColumns functionality. My objective is to generate a table from a JSON object and have the first column fixed upon horizontal scroll.
However, I'm encountering an issue with achieving this intended behavior. The first column does not stay fixed upon horizontal scroll, unless the page has been resized. I am uncertain as to why this behavior is occurring and how to ensure it stays fixed upon page load.
Despite my efforts to find this answer in the docs, I've been unable to do so.
Here's the initialization code,
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jszip-3.10.1/dt-2.0.2/af-2.7.0/b-3.0.1/b-html5-3.0.1/fc-5.0.0/fh-4.0.1/kt-2.12.0/r-3.0.0/rg-1.5.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jszip-3.10.1/dt-2.0.2/af-2.7.0/b-3.0.1/b-html5-3.0.1/fc-5.0.0/fh-4.0.1/kt-2.12.0/r-3.0.0/rg-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

    // Initialize the DataTable
    var table = $('#example-table').DataTable({
        fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: 1 // fix only the first column
        },
        paging: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scrollX: true,
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip', // Add button container to the DataTable
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excel'
        }]
    });

